# Create "sound bars" similar to the bars in windows mediaplayer

Tags: android, charts, media-player, android-mediaplayer, javasound

I have no idea what these bars represent, but still I want to make them in my app on Android platform.
I want that the bars to change on a sound or in my case a recorded sample play.

For http://www.teamliquid.net/blogs/viewblog.php?topic_id=90197&docid=Cw1ObF4XGZQD4M&imgurl=http://i658.photobucket.com/albums/uu307/StimedFirebat/bars.jpg&w=1024&h=819&ei=0-6jT76WOc_U8QO-psyDCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=812&vpy=156&dur=1559&hovh=201&hovw=251&tx=157&ty=133&sig=110361762640680792178&page=1&tbnh=154&tbnw=186&start=0&ndsp=28&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:72&biw=1680&bih=864">example the bars that windows media player displays while playing music.

Comment: why implement something when you don't even know what it is?

Comment: i dont have to know what is it... i just know what i want in my app... i would love to learn if you have a tutorial to give me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at this: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/tree/4054f8b6e2153b07c5af275372b9609d1019727a. this is a project with line, circle, and bar visualizers

and btw google beforehand.

Comment: i searched google... just didnt knew the name of thiese bars... :/

Comment: oh. um well yeah if u need help just ask. the visualizers are kinda my thing

Answer (score -1):

The moving bars are called a graphical equaliser. I think this media API sample uses one.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html

Comment: can you specify exactly in which sample project folder

Comment: @SwapAndroid Link is now broken, try the wayback machine http://web.archive.org/web/20120112061650/http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html

Comment: dude i tried that it is working.. but i want to display it like Bar like windows media player... i found one "pheelicks.app" to display visualizer in different format but graphics is very poor for bar visualizer

Comment: Sorry I can't be much more help. I was just highlighting some example code for an Equaliser